# How to setup 2 monitors and specify workplaces?

Tags: xorg

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 desktop with 2 monitors and I want to use a specific workplace shown only on my 2nd monitor. When I switch workplaces on my 1st monitor, I don't want the 2nd one to be affected.

For example; I am running a VM or a terminal window on one of my workplaces and assign that workplace to my 2nd monitor so even if I switch between workplaces on my 1st monitor, I can still see the terminal or a VM on my 2nd one. Is there an option like that to assign a workplace on a specific monitor?

I have NVIDIA Quadro 2000 graphic card on my system.

Comment: I know the gnome desktop environment behaves like that by default if I remember correct, but I don't know if you can do that in unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign separate workspaces for your monitors with Unitiy and Compiz.

A workaround that does the trick for many people is simply use the **Always on Visible Workspace** setting that can be accessed by right clicking on a window's top bar when it is not maximized.
This way the the windows set to use this option will stay in position when you change workspaces.

For real separate workspaces for your monitors you would need to use another desktop environment and/or window manager.